# Mapbox GL - How to populate custom icons using vector source?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

When reading examples of Mapbox GL using custom markers,  I've seen examples - ie:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/
where geojson data is hard coded (geometry) and icons can be custom selected for the map...

In a quick example that I've created :   https://jsfiddle.net/claybox7/cmh3qw22/8/
I'm using a 'vector'  geometry  source saved in mapbox .
When it is run, it will show circles of the provided long/lat from my data source.

How would I create markers  like the  "icon": "monument" ones used in the mapbox gl example above instead of circles to represent my geometry points?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the type of your layer from *circle* to *symbol* and add an *icon-image* at the *layout* properties. The code should look like this:

```
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'schoolData',
  'type': 'symbol',
  'source': 'schoolData',
  'layout': {
     'visibility': 'visible',
     'icon-image': 'monument-15'
  }, ...
});
```

All possible default icons can be found at [Github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-styles).

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks!  - Here's the updated jsfiddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/cmh3qw22/9/